# Having difficulty in evaluating a definite integral by substitution.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

The question is this - 
$$I =\int_{-1}^1 \frac{e^{1/x}}{x^2(1+e^{2/x})}dx $$

So I started by substituting $\frac{1}{x}=t \rightarrow \frac{-1}{x^2}dx=dt. $
$$I=-\int_{-1}^1 \frac{e^t}{1+e^{2t}}dt$$

Then I go for $e^t=u \rightarrow e^tdt=du.$
$$I=-\int_{\frac{1}{e}}^e \frac{du}{1+u^2}$$

$$I=-\left(\tan^{-1}(e)-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)\right)$$

$$I=\cot^{-1}e-\tan^{-1}e$$

$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}-2\tan^{-1}e$$

But this seems to be wrong,  as the answer given is $$I=\pi - 2\tan^{-1}e$$

They have solved by splitting the integral from $-1 \rightarrow 0$ and $0 \rightarrow 1$. Their solution seems to be correct too. But I can not understand my mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Let $y=e^{1/x}$, and you will be awarded.

Comment: there's a discontinuity at $x=0$ so you should split the integral into pieces there

Comment: @danimal If one defines the function to be 0 at 0, it becomes infinitely smooth.

Comment: @mickep I didn't understand what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: By $\frac1x=t$, when $x$ varies from $-1$ to $1$, what about $t$?